# How to synchronise files from more than one folder between Ftp and local folder using Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Collegues, i'am  trying to download folders with files from sftp using spring integration.

I can synchronised files from one single folders `20161207`:

```
@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
   SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer =
      new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
   fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
   fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/pub/op/20161207/");
   fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
   return fileSynchronizer;
}
```

But what should i do if need to download (synchronised) files from more than one folder (`20161208`, `20161209` etc)?
Have you any example? 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I tried to use SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter, but it didn't help:

```
  @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/pub/op/");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.xml$");
        SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter sftpRegexPatternFileListFilter  = new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(pattern);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(sftpRegexPatternFileListFilter);
        //fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
```

**UPDATE** 
Code is replac4ed here according to advice:

```
@Bean @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel") 
    public MessageHandler handler() 
    { SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "MGET", "payload"); 
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound")); 
        return sftpOutboundGateway;}
```

**UPDATE**
Artem, Gary, thank you for help.
This is my code:
     @Bean
        public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {

```
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(server);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setUser(login);
        factory.setPassword(pass);
        factory.setTimeout(60*1000);
        return factory;
    }


@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mget", "getPayload() == '/pub/op/20170130/test.xml'");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("C:/test/gateway/"));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

When i start application i receive the next output

```
12:25:58.593 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor : Starting beans in phase -2147483648
12:25:58.593 INFO  [main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Adding {sftp:outbound-gateway:aameFtpConfig.handler.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'sftpChannel' channel
12:25:58.593 INFO  [main] o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel : Channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4157f54e.sftpChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
12:25:58.593 INFO  [main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : started aameFtpConfig.handler.serviceActivator
12:25:58.594 INFO  [main] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor : Starting beans in phase 0
12:25:58.594 INFO  [main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
12:25:58.594 INFO  [main] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel : Channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4157f54e.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
12:25:58.594 INFO  [main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
```

But file is not copied into `"C:/test/gateway/"`.
Plase, tel me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SftpOutboundGateway` with `MGET` command.

That dynamic remote directory can be as request message.

The polling logic you can achieve with raw method invoking Inbound Channel Adapter. And this one can generate the directory name to send.

You may consider to use Idempotent Receiver after gateway to be sure do not process the same files again.

The Sftp Inbound Channel Adapter can't do that for you because its purpose to check the same resource for new data.

Comment: Since version 4.2, you can use `synchronizer.setRemoteDirectoryExpression` to use a SpEL expression to generate the directory that will be checked on each poll - you can rotate through multiple directories that way - but there is no way to scan multiple directories on a single poll; and they will all be pulled to the same local directory. As @Artem says, you can use MGET (with recursion) to fetch from multiple directories.

Comment: I'am new in Spring... Do i need to add bean like :` @Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new  SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "MGET", "payload");
             
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
         return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }`  in my config?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the is no way to make `SftpOutboundGateway` working

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; as you can see, it renders poorly and is hardly readable. Instead, edit your question and add a comment to indicate you have done so (we don't get notifications of edits).